# Microsoft.AspNet.Cryptography.KeyDerivation vs System.Security.Cryptography

Tags: c#, .net, performance, security, password-hash

I lately noticed extremely slow performance of System.Security.Cryptography.

To generate hash for password with 100000 iterations it took ~3 seconds.

Similar code using Microsoft.AspNet.Cryptography for same configuration for hash took around 10x less time.

Code I used to test is

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Cryptography.KeyDerivation;

namespace CryptoTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            Crypto crypto = new Crypto();
            Console.WriteLine($"Iterations: {test.HashIterations}, KeySize: {test.KeySize}, SaltSize: {test.DefaultSaltSize}");
            var salt = test.GenerateSalt();
            string password = "Very C0mplicated-AnD_L0ng.P@ssw0rd!";
            var saltedHashOld = crypto.GenerateSaltedHash(password, salt);
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Time elapsed: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
            Console.WriteLine(saltedHashOld);

            watch.Reset();
            watch.Start();
            var prf = KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA1;
            var saltedHash = crypto.GenerateSaltedHash(password, salt, prf);
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"using {prf}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Time elapsed: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
            Console.WriteLine(saltedHash);


            watch.Reset();
            watch.Start();
            prf = KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA256;
            saltedHash = crypto.GenerateSaltedHash(password, salt, prf);
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"using {prf}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Time elapsed: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
            Console.WriteLine(saltedHash);

            watch.Reset();
            watch.Start();
            prf = KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA512;
            saltedHash = crypto.GenerateSaltedHash(password, salt, prf);
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"using {prf}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Time elapsed: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
            Console.WriteLine(saltedHash);
            Console.WriteLine("finished");
        }
    }
    public class Crypto
    {
        public int HashIterations => 100000;
        public int DefaultSaltSize => 96;
        public int KeySize => 96;
        public KeyDerivationPrf Prf => KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA1;

        public string GenerateSaltedHash(string password, string salt)
        {
            return ComputeHash(HashIterations, password, salt, KeySize);
        }

        public string GenerateSaltedHash(string password, string salt, KeyDerivationPrf prf)
        {
            return ComputeHash(HashIterations, password, salt, KeySize, prf);
        }

        public string GenerateSalt()
        {
            var rand = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
            var ret = new byte[DefaultSaltSize];
            rand.GetBytes(ret);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(ret);
        }

        private string ComputeHash(int iterationsNo, string plainText, string salt, int keySize)
        {
            byte[] saltBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt);
            var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(plainText, saltBytes, iterationsNo);
            var key = pbkdf2.GetBytes(keySize);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(key);
        }

        private string ComputeHash(int iterationsNo, string plainText, string salt, int keySize, KeyDerivationPrf prf)
        {
            byte[] saltBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt);
            var key = KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(plainText, saltBytes, prf, iterationsNo, keySize);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(key);
        }
    }
}
```

If I compare to default settings of Python Django framework login, it is on 300000 iterations and still does password hashing with less than a second, with System.Security.Cryptography it would take way too long time to authenticate the password on login if the iteration count is raised to current standards.

**Which one should be used?**

or am I missing here something?

Comment: You're probably also measuring JIT & DLL load time.

Comment: Measured already in `release mode` of the compiler?

Comment: Tried in Visual Studio, both debug and also release.

Comment: The reason I started to look into it was the password hashing in backend. Client  TTFB took 2.7 - 3.0 sec from backend authentication endpoint. Compiled service, so I don't think JIT or DLL load time are there to affect the time that much. 
Even when testing 3 sec vs 0.3 sec is huge difference.